# NODEMON — app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

When I run `npm start server` I get the error:

Why does this happen? Is Port 5000 already in use?

Here's the terminal:

```
C:\Users\Sakib\chat-application\router\loginRouter.js:10 

router.get("/", loginController); 
                ^

ReferenceError: loginController is not defined

    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sakib\chat-application\router\loginRouter.js:10:17)

    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sakib\chat-application\app.js:7:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 `[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: because you are referencing to a function named `loginController` which does not exist (at least not in the scope) ...

Comment: i already did it and made another folder with the name of `loginController` as per the following path of it.

Comment: Can you add the `loginController` and the `loginRouter` code to the question? Then it'll be easier to explain the solution :)

Comment: @RukshanJayasekara  here i write the code of `loginController` and `LoginRounter` in the comment section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**loginController**

```
    //get login page
function getLogin(req, res, next) {
  res.render("index", {
    title: "login - Chat Application",
  });
}

module.exports = {
  getLogin,
};
```

**loginRouter**

```
//external imports
const express = require("express");

//internal imports
const { getLogin } = require("../controller/loginController");

const router = express.Router();

//login page
router.get("/", loginController);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: This is not an answer, so you should put that code in your question.

Comment: Nonetheless, eventhough your module is called `loginController` the imported function is called `getLogin`. So you must use `router.get("/", getLogin)`

Answer (score 0):

as what @derpirscher said, you are referencing the wrong variable in your `loginRouter.js`

```js
//external imports
const express = require("express");

//internal imports
const { getLogin } = require("../controller/loginController");

const router = express.Router();

//login page
router.get("/", getLogin); // **Change this line**

module.exports = router;
```